# Responsive menu html css on small screens

Tags: html, css

I want to make a responsive menu with only html and css , no Javascript.
I'm still practising.. maybe anyone can see why my menu doesn't appear when clicking on the label?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Frank.css">
    <meta name="author" content="Frank Van Hoek">
    <title>Frank</title>   
</head>

<body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo" class="cfx">
                <a href="away.html"><img class="imglogo" class="cfx" src="afbeeldingen/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="facebook" class="cfx"></div>
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/5254824441/?fref=ts"><img class="facebook" class="cfx" src="afbeeldingen/facebook.png" alt="facebook"> </a>

        </header>
    <div class="wrapper" class="cfx">

        <nav class="normaal" class="cfx">
            <ul class="menu" class="cfx">
                <li class="actief"><a href="Frank.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="leden.html">Leden</a></li>
                <li><a href="parken.html">Parken</a></li>
                <li><a href="evenementen.html">Evenementen</a></li>
                <li><a href="overons.html">Over ons</a></li>
            </ul>                                        
        </nav>


        /************HAMBURGER***************/

        <nav class="hamburger">
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
            <label for="menu-toggle"></label>

            <ul>
                <li class="actief"><a href="Frank.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="leden.html">Leden</a></li>
                <li><a href="parken.html">Parken</a></li>
                <li><a href="evenementen.html">Evenementen</a></li>
                <li><a href="overons.html">Over ons</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <div class="content" class="cfx">
          <h2>BMX : Streetculture in Antwerp</h1>
            <video controls><source src="afbeeldingen/StreetcultureInAntwerp.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
            <p>Onze A.Way leden in dit filmpje zijn Tarik Begdouri, Zeno Peeters, Koen Vanden Broeck en Dimitri Huybrechts. De andere rijders zijn Niels Mertens, Stef de Backer, Brian O' Brien, Jonas van Oosterbosch en Juno Vereecken. Het werd gefilmd en gemonteerd door onze rijder Ilyas Deckers en de achtergrondmuziek is "Al'Tarba Vs Lord Lhus - 3 Amigos feat Dirty Dike & Jace Abstract".</p>

            <h1>Nieuwsfeeds</h1>
            <div class="nieuwsfeed">
                <p class="bericht">
                    Dit weekend is het de 'Braaab BMX Contest 2015' in '040 BMX park' in Eindhoven. Dit wil je niet missen! Meer informatie vind je op de <a href="https://www.facebook.com/events/1012608095435859/">facebookpagina</a>.
                </p>
                <p class="datum">
                    4 maart 2015
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="nieuwsfeed">
                <p class="bericht">
                    Iemand die deze rail durft te grinden? - Locatie: Aan de schelde, niet ver van ATV
                </p>
                <p class="datum">
                    2 maart 2015
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="nieuwsfeed">
                <p class="bericht">
                    Reminder!!! Deze zondag 2de meeting ivm Bmx jam stadspark - Locatie: Fietsenfikser - Tijdstip: 13u
                </p>
                <p class="datum">
                    26 februari 2015
                </p>
            </div>

             <div class="nieuwsfeed">   
                <p class="bericht">
                    Deze vrijdag Pizza Friday om 5u in het Stadspark! Be there!
                </p>
                <p class="datum">
                    25 februari 2015
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <p>© All rights reserved - 2015</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html
{
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
height:100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

img , video;
{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

body
{
height:inherit;
margin: inherit;
padding: inherit;
background-color: #000;
}

.wrapper
{
max-width: 900px;
min-width: 400px;
min-height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #000;
}

header
{
background-image:url(afbeeldingen/skyline.png);
margin: auto;
height: 336px;
width: inherit;
}

.logo
{
padding: 0 1.25em;
float: left;
}

.imglogo
{
width: 170px;
height: 170px;
}

.facebook
{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

nav
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

ul.menu
{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 5px 10% 5px 10%;
padding: 5px auto 5px auto;
left: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.menu li
{
float:left;
margin: 5px auto 5px auto;
padding: 0px 1.875em 0px 1.875em;
background-color: #000;
text-align: center;
}

.menu li:first-child
{
padding: 0px 1.875em 0px 1.875em;
}

.menu li > a
{
display: block;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}

.menu li:hover, li.actief
{
background-color: #f08222;
}

.menu li:hover > a, li.actief >a
{
color: #000;
}

.hamburger
{
    display: none;
}

.content
{
    color: #fff;
    display:block;
    margin: 50px 7.7777777777777777777777777777778% 70px 7.7777777777777777777777777777778%;
}

.content video
{
    width: 760px;
    height: auto;
}

.content h1
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.nieuwsfeed
{
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 0.625em;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.datum
{
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.content a:link 
{
    color: #f08222;
}

.content a:visited
{
    color: #e2ff00;
}

footer p
{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 200px auto 40px auto;
}


/**************************
    *    MEDIA QUERY        *
    *************************/


@media screen and (max-width: 820px)
{
html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
                    margin: 0;
                    overflow-x: hidden;
                    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                }

        .normaal
        {
            display:none;
        }

        .hamburger
        {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #menu-toggle {
            display: none;
        }

        #menu-toggle:checked ~ .hamburger ul{
            left:0;
        }

        #menu-toggle:checked ~ .content {
            left:240px;
        }

        #menu-toggle:checked + label {
            left:250px;
        }

        label[for="menu-toggle"] {
            position: fixed;
            left:60px;
            top:300px;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: #0f0;
            z-index: 2;
        }

        .hamburger ul{
            position: fixed;
            width: 240px;
            height: 100%;
            top:300px;
            left: -240px;
            background-color: #e34dd2;
            color: white;
        }

        .hamburger ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

        .hamburger li a {
            display: block;
            padding:0.5em 1em;
            color: white;
            border-bottom: 1px #424240 solid;
        }

        .container {
            position: relative;
            left:0;
            padding: 2em;
        }

        nav, .container, label[for="menu-toggle"] {
            -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
            transition: left 0.5s;
        }
}


 /*************************
    *     C L E A R F I X    *
    *************************/

.cfx::before, .cfx::after {
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
    content: "";
}

.cfx::after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: 1) line bashing is not a good way to get past the 'your post is mostly code' thing. 2) use JS fiddle 3) why don't you use bootstrap for it? Bootstrap is a great way for beginners to make good sites and have a look at how it is done.

Comment: Please check this example http://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/CLIsl

Comment: It is for school and I have to do it this way

Comment: I've already seen that example 'Kumar' but I can't find my mistake

Comment: Well, this is strange... I see my first and last name in the question. This video `afbeeldingen/StreetcultureInAntwerp.mp4` is filmed by me. OP, can you contact me?

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to use a responsive framework, such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).

Here is a simplistic example for a responsive navigation menu which utilises bootstrap.

[Responsive navigation bar Preview](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/) 
[Responsive navigation bar Download](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/)

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
.hamburger ul{
        position: fixed;
        width: 240px;
        height: 100%;
        top:300px;
        left: -240px;
        background-color: #e34dd2;
        color: white;
    }
```

`position: fixed;` means that its position values are in relation to the window/viewport. So having `left: -240px;` will move this element *out* of the viewport (i.e. make it invisible). Do you really want this? Even if that's intentionally and supposed to work together with this rule

```
 #menu-toggle:checked ~ .hamburger ul{
        left:0;
    }
```

...to move it in, they are in the wrong order - the former rule will most likely overwrite the other one, making the element invisible...